# SwingWorker makes code hard to read

Tags: java, swing, coding-style, swingworker

I enjoy using SwingWorker to cope with tasks which take much time but I found that it makes my code hard to read. Example:

Before I had:

```
classCombo.setModel(Controller.getAllClasses());
```

And now:

```
private void downloadData()
{

    final WaitDialog waitDialog = new WaitDialog(this);
    SwingWorker<Object, Void> sw = new SwingWorker<Object, Void>()
    {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    waitDialog.start(null);
                }
            });
            return Controller.getAllClasses();
        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            Vector<KlasaEntity> klasy = null;
            try
            {
                klasy = (Vector<KlasaEntity>) get();
                waitDialog.stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            classCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<KlasaEntity>(klasy));
        }

    };
    sw.execute();
```

Do you see any chance to make this code shorter?

Comment: I don't think you can reduce your code. You can make the code a bit more readable. However, I am not sure if that is what you are interested in, are you?

Comment: I want tu reduce lines of code. I thought about writing custom class which will take in constructor some arguments, functions references (like delegates in c#)

Comment: Yes I would have suggested something similar but that will not reduce lines of code. It will only improve your organization and readability. I think it would be a good idea.